# Increment row in search code Excel Vba

Tags: excel, vba, increment

I am stuck on problem where my vba won't increment row number. My tables looks like:
Sheet1

```
name value  
aa  11  
bb  12  
cc  13  
aa  14  
cc  15  
cc  16  
aa  17  
bb  18  
aa  19
```

Sheet2

```
name
aa
bb
cc
```

I need to search for each specific value, if found copy adjacent cell to sheet2 right next searched value. This is code doing but problem is with row incrementation, all searched values are in one row (variable k is not working).

```
Sub finall()
Dim cable As String
Dim finalrow1 As Integer
Dim finalrow2 As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Integer
l = 2
k = 2
finalrow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
finalrow1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
For j = 2 To finalrow2
    cable = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value
    For i = 2 To finalrow1
        If Cells(i, 1) = cable Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(k, l).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
            l = l + 1
        End If
    Next i
    k = k + 1
Next j
End Sub
```

This is only example in final i want to apply this code to table with 50-60k rows.

Final table should look like:

```
name                
aa  11  14  17  19
bb  12  18      
cc  13  15  16
```

Thx

Comment: Try: `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Sry, post updated. Where i should add your proposed code. I am new with excel vba. TY

Comment: Take a look at this line: `finalrow2 = ...` and `finalrow1 = ...`

Comment: please check my edit. if its look good please mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final code would be as below

```
Sub finall()
    Dim cable As String
    Dim finalrow1 As Long
    Dim finalrow2 As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim l As Long
    l = 2
    k = 2
    finalrow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
    finalrow1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
    For j = 2 To finalrow2
        cable = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value
        For i = 2 To finalrow1
            If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = cable Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Copy
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(k, l).PasteSpecial
                l = l + 1
            End If
        Next i
        k = k + 1
        l = 2
    Next j
End Sub
```

**Proof of work**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Code Works fine but there is one problem. Value 16 belongs to cc not bb :/

Comment: Great, work like a charm. Thank you. I will apply this on big table. :)

Comment: Maybe one more question, i have got "Overflow" error if I increase range in "finalrowX" definition (to a bit more than number of rows), big table has 55149 rows (Sheet1) and 42168 unique values (sheet2). is there any way how to override this? Again thanks

Comment: try `finalrow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` and `finalrow1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: i did, but still overflow problem, if i change finalrow1, finalrow2, i and j variables from integer to long, program start but after while if will freeze :(

Comment: Run-time error '9': Subscription out of range.. only if i change the data type to long, program start but after while whole excel freeze and i need to restart it

Comment: declaring Long does not through any error at my end

Comment: can you please post your excel online?

Comment: see the edit. I have changed all the integer to Long. Surely, It will work for you now

Comment: i found the same but problem with excel freeze persist :(

Comment: seems your data is too long. since it takes time to complete all the rows. kindly be patient. i am also running your code. will post it if doesnot freeze

Comment: hello, so thank for all your help.... i moved job on different pc and its running now.. looks like page file on current pc is too small to handle all operations...

Comment: Great. Good to know